# Do I need to manually repartition a big csv file when I read it with spark.read

Tags: apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

I have a big CSV file on my local disk 10GB (no HDFS).

I read it with:

```
val df = spark.read.format("csv").load("file:///data/big.csv")
```

Do I need to repartition (or manually split) it before doing some transformations or actions on it or does spark dataframe will do this for me automatically?

When I was using RDD I needed to repartition it to get more than 1 core working on it but with DF I do not know.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Spark by default created `200 shuffle partition`. So you don't need to do it manually.  However to improve performance you can choose to repartition data. However make sure that it will do the full shuffle of table data.

Comment: I think 200 is when you shuffe like for a join, not for a basic file read

Comment: @Benjamin yes, whenever it need to shuffle a data it does that. What you can do is check the spark UI and see how much each partition shuffles data. if it's too low or uneven you can think of doing reparitition.

Comment: The question is more how to force having more than one task for first map for example. Problem can be solved if file is split on the hard drive but I would like to avoid it